# JavaSrpipt Промисы

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

Учу js

Вопрос про Промисы:

Почему в коде ниже,
вызов "bike.valIncrement();" происводит инкремент
только один раз, а потом значение не меняется

```js
const Bike = function(val){
  this.val = val;
}

Bike.prototype.valIncrement = function() { 
  let currentIndex = this['val'];
  this.changeGearAsync(currentIndex)
    .then(
      (newIndex) => {
        console.log(newIndex);
        this['val'] = newIndex;
    }
  )
    .catch(
      (err) => {console.log("Error: " + err);}
    );
};

Bike.prototype.changeGearAsync = function(currentIndex){

  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => { 
      let newIndex = currentIndex + 1; 
      resolve(newIndex);
    }
  )
};

const bike = new Bike(val = 5);
console.log(bike);

bike.valIncrement(); // 6
bike.valIncrement(); // 6
bike.valIncrement(); // 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Если в вашем коде где-то появляется асинхронность, остаётся забыть про синхронные вызовы и работать только асинхронно. В таких случаях говорят, что асинхронность «заразна». Возвращайте промис в `valIncrement()` и вызывайте изменения в цепочке асинхронных вызовов, например.

```js
const Bike = function(val){
  this.val = val;
}

Bike.prototype.valIncrement = function() {
  let currentIndex = this['val'];

  return this.changeGearAsync(currentIndex)
    .then(
      (newIndex) => {

        console.log(newIndex);

        this['val'] = newIndex;

    }
  )
    .catch(
      (err) => {console.log("Error: " + err);}
    );
};

Bike.prototype.changeGearAsync = function(currentIndex){

  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {

      let newIndex = currentIndex + 1;
      resolve(newIndex);

    }
  )
};

const bike = new Bike(5);
console.log(bike.val);

bike.valIncrement()
  .then(() => { bike.valIncrement(); })
  .then(() => { bike.valIncrement(); });
```

Comment: а лучше переписать через async/await, читаемость и более прозрачные вызовы

Answer (score 1):

**Почему в коде ниже, вызов "bike.valIncrement();" происводит инкремент только один раз, а потом значение не меняется** - инкремент производится 3 раза. Только вот захвата тоже 3 и все они захватили значение 5. И инкрементируют 5 и присваивают его соответственно.

Поскольку вся сложность промисов заключается в понимании асинхронности. Вызов конструктора промиса означает возрашение этого объекта тут же а вот методы  `resolve` `reject` будут выполняться после когда осносной поток освободиться и возмет данные из Event Loop

```js
const Bike = function(val){
  this.val = val;
}

Bike.prototype.valIncrement = function() { 
  let currentIndex = this['val'];
  console.log(currentIndex);

  this.changeGearAsync(currentIndex)
    .then(
      (newIndex) => {

        console.log(newIndex);

        this['val'] = newIndex;

    }
  )
    .catch(
      (err) => {console.log("Error: " + err);}
    );
};

Bike.prototype.changeGearAsync = function(currentIndex){

  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
    
      let newIndex = currentIndex + 1; 
      resolve(newIndex);

    }
  )
};

const bike = new Bike(val = 5);

bike.valIncrement(); // 6
bike.valIncrement(); // 6
bike.valIncrement(); // 6
```